# Shiny in R: Assigning reactive to reactive

Tags: r, shiny, reactive

I am building a Shiny App in R and I am trying to assign a reactive function to a reactive object. But I'm getting the error and I don't know how to fix this issue.

my server.R is,

```
path_group  <- '/home/makoto/shinyFiles/custom/groups/'
group_livre <- reactive({paste0(path_group, input$client,'.csv')})


# getFilterExport is a function that I made. 
# It fetches a list of data frames.
# The list contains four data frames including $affrete.

list_attribute <- reactive({getFilterExport(connectionDb, input$client)})


# renaming is a data frame with two columns($Name and $Paired)
renaming <- reactive({read.csv(group_livre(), 
                             header = T, sep = ';', 
                             stringsAsFactors = F )[,1:2]})


# Replace the values in list_attribute()$affrete to renaming$Name
# only when it matches renaming$Paired
affrete <- reactive({
    plyr::mapvalues(x = unlist(list_attribute()$affrete, use.names = F),
                               from = as.character(renaming()$Paired),
                               to = as.character(renaming()$Name))
})

list_attribute()$affrete$affrete <- reactive({affrete()})
liste_trans <- reactive({list_attribute()$affrete$affrete})
```

And I get this kind of error:

```
Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext() : 
Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. 
(You tried to do something that can only be done from 
 inside a reactive expression or observer.)
```

The input from the ui.R side is only `input$client`, and this input reactivates `group_livre`, `list_attribute`, `renaming`, `affrete`, `list_attribute()$affrete$affrete` and `liste_trans`. I've been playing around which to make reactive and which not to, but in any cases I get more or less the same error.

Basically what I want to ask is,

1. I know that `group_livre` and `list_attribute` have to be reactive functions. But should the rest of `renaming`, `affrete`, `list_attribute()$affrete$affrete` and `liste_trans` should also be reactive functions as well?
2. When you call a reactive object, you have to add () after the object. Is there any mistakes above regarding this point? When you want to assign reactive functions to already-reactive objects, is it allowed to write like `list_attribute()$affrete()$affrete()`?

I would appreciate it if anyone could help me out!

Comment: try this.. list_attribute <- reactive({client <- input$client
getFilterExport(connectionDb, client)})

Comment: thank you! but it does not work... why is it supposed to work?